# Ascensor JS not loading at correct position - Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, loading

Ive built a website using the [ascensor js plugin](http://www.kirkas.ch/ascensor/)
Its all working fine except in Internet Explorer. The first time you go to the site, it will load correctly. If you refresh your page it sometimes works. If you clear your cache or clear history and go to the website it will not load correctly. The URL will be correct but the page it shows will not.It should show the 2nd level, but shows the 1st level.

Ive tried looking at other sites using the plugin but they all have there sites loading on level 1. The code I use to load it is below. The WindowsOn:2, should be making it load at level 2. Ive tried modifying my JavaScript but have had no luck.

Can anyone help me with a fix or an alternative to get it loading at the correct position.
www.newworldwhisky.com.au

Thanks

```
$('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor({
    AscensorName:'ascensor',
    ChildType:'section',
    AscensorFloorName:'starward | home | distillery | our_history | our_team | process_and_innovation | participate | buy_our_whisky | work_with_us | news_and_events | contact_us | media',
    Time:700,
    Easing:'easeInOutCubic',
    WindowsOn:2,
    Direction:'chocolate',
    AscensorMap:'1|1 & 2|1 & 3|1 & 3|2 & 3|3 & 3|4 & 4|1 & 4|2 & 4|3 & 4|4 & 5|1 & 5|2',
    KeyNavigation: true,
    Queued:false,
    QueuedDirection:"x"
});
```

Ive also attached a screen shot of the error. The first is how it should load, the second is the error.

[Loading error screenshot](http://newworldwhisky.com.au/load_error.jpg)

Comment: Have found that firefox throws no errors but chrome throws one if you click the media page link. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Comment: Managed to fix the Uncaught type error issue but still having the issue in IE. The uncaught type error was due to a mismatched link

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding the solution. The canvas tags were withing the ascensor building that the plugin uses to hold all the pages. I moved it outside of that and it fixed the loading issue in IE